# Simulator bitcoin miner

Tags: c++

I was checking this C++ mining project to start with Bitcoin mining and understand better how mining works.

This is the project: https://github.com/gavinandresen/bitcoin_miningsim

But now i want to experiment with one real situation to verify what will happen. What more do I need to implement? I need to include the connection to my pool and then let the miners work to send the different blocks that they are mining?

I am little lost so if someone can tell me if this a good example for learning or know others that can help me.

Comment: For a mining simulator: https://jornc.github.io/bitcoin-transaction-explorer/

Comment: ok so this is program is not necessary i think seeing one simulator like you took me it's more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are linking to is for simulating network-like effects of various mining technologies and policies. It does not actually mine, and will not teach you about mining itself.

You may look up projects like cgminer of bfgminer for actual mining software.